# MySQL FULLTEXT Score from multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to search a MySQL Database of maintenance records for trucks. The tables I am searching are Maintenance, Truck, and maintenance_parts. What do I need to do to get the FULLTEXT score from the Truck and Maintenance_Parts tables to add to the score from the Maintenance Table?

```
SELECT maintenance_id, some_id, type_code, service_date, mileage, mg_id, mg_type, comments, work_done,
    MATCH(comments, work_done) AGAINST( 'valve tire' ) AS score
    FROM maintenance
    WHERE  type_code = 'truck'
    AND some_id IN (
        SELECT truck_id FROM truck 
        WHERE MATCH( truck_number, make, model, engine, vin_number, transmission_number, comments) AGAINST( 'P' )
        OR truck_number LIKE '%P%'
    )
    AND maintenance_id IN( 
        SELECT maintenance_id FROM maintenance_parts WHERE MATCH( part_num, part_desc, part_ref) AGAINST( 'valve tire' )
    )
    OR MATCH(comments, work_done) AGAINST( 'valve tire' )
    AND status = 'A' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the query to eliminate the subqueries, and do it with joins instead. Once the subqueries' fulltext searches are moved up to the parent query, you should be able to join the scores there.

Comment: match a word/string with single character length is very bad ...

Comment: @Marc B - Thanks that worked. If you add your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @ajreal - The single character is needed to find vehicle ID numbers because many of the trucks and trailers are numbered F1, F2... P1, P2... S1, S2...

Comment: ic, I guess an extra column contains the first character of the ID is better that `%P%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to rewrite the query to eliminate the subqueries, and do it with joins instead. Once the subqueries' fulltext searches are moved up to the parent query, you should be able to join the scores there.